# Why leads deletion of UUIDField to Django SystemCheckError

Tags: python, django, system-error

I've been building a Django website and included a UUID field "customer_id" in my initial "Customer" model. Finally, I decided to drop it. But when I try to delete it from my models.py, Django throws

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
<class 'accounts.admin.CustomerAdmin'>: (admin.E035) The value of 'readonly_fields[1]' is not a callable, an attribute of 'CustomerAdmin', or an attribute of 'accounts.Customer'.
```

Here is the code of **models.py**

```py
    from django.db import models
    import uuid
    
    # Create a base model to make sure we keep track of creation and edits
    class ModelBaseClass(models.Model):
        date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
        date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    
        class Meta:
            abstract = True
    
    # Create your models here.
    class Customer(ModelBaseClass):
        customer_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, #this is the field i try to drop
                                   editable=False, 
                                   unique=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
        email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
            
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

**What I tried so far:**

I suspect that this could be related to existing data or some other dependencies. So...

1. I deleted the sqlite database, deleted all migration files and ran
   `"python manage.py makemigrations"` and `"python manage.py migrate"`.
2. I ran `python manage.py flush`.
3. I also tried to change the `editable=False` to `editable=True` and migrate before dropping,
   but it didn't change anything.

It's perhaps also worth mentioning that my "Customer" model a relation to another model.

Could someone explain me why Django is preventing me from deleting this field and how to resolve this?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Because you have a `CustomerAdmin` where you use the `customer_id`, and now that is no longer available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could someone explain me what's going on and how to resolve this?

As the error says, you have a model admin named `CustomerAdmin`. Indeed:

```
<class 'accounts.admin.CustomerAdmin'>: (admin.E035) The value of 'readonly_fields[1]' is not a callable, an attribute of 'CustomerAdmin', or an attribute of 'accounts.Customer'.
```

For the `readonly_fields`, it lists the `customer_id`, but since that field is no longer available, it raises the error.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more specific.

Comment: Took me a bit to understand what you ment with "you have a model admin named CustomerAdmin" but you are 100% right. To clarify for other users: in my `admin.py` file I added a ModelAdmin named `CustomerAdmin` which specifies `readonly_fields`. One of the fields referenced there was "customer_id". (I had added it a while ago to override the read-only fields and completely forgot about it) This reference was what Django was complaining about. After deleting the reference in there, I was able to delete the UUIDField in `models.py` without any issue.